# Envoyproxy not work in DAPR environment on Docker-Compose

Tags: envoyproxy, dapr

I'm using docker-compose for local debug for microservices application.
I want ENVOY as Application Gateway and DAPR as Microservices framework.
I create ENVOY container and ENVOY-DAPR for sidecard container that redirect request to correct dapr microservices.

Docker-Compose: https://github.com/andreatosato/DAPR-samples/blob/main/docker-compose.yml

Docker-Compose-Override: https://github.com/andreatosato/DAPR-samples/blob/main/docker-compose.override.yml

When call this:
http://localhost:10000/c/weather

I have this response:
upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure

This project is for personal learning, so, you can download it and try all.

Answer (score 0):

In catalog-api you did not specify for "weather"
Call this instead "api/v1/WeatherForecast"
http://localhost:10000/c/api/v1/WeatherForecast